# Entries tag showing pages not in the current Structure path

Tags: structure, url

Has anyone else experienced pages showing up that shouldn't be when using the Structure module?

For example, let's say I have a channel called Pages and a page structure like so in the Structure module:

```
+ Parent Page         (structure url: parent, template: parent/index)
|- Sub Page           (structure url: child1, template: parent/child)
|- Sub Page           (structure url: child2, template: parent/child)
|- Sub Page           (structure url: child3, template: parent/child)
+ Parent Sibling Page (structure url: sibling, template: sibling/index)
```

Currently the channel entries tag looks like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages"
  disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
  cache="yes" refresh="180" require_entry="yes" limit="1"}
```

Nothing unusual there. So no surprises when we see the correct page showing when navigating to `mysite.com/parent/child1`.

However, if we changed the URL in the address bar to go to `mysite.com/parent/sibling` I **do not** expect to see the parent's sibling page... it's not in the same path at all!

After some investigation, it appears that the channel entries tag is simply falling back on its default functionality, but that is far from desired in this scenario, especially as we have strict URLs on.

Any clues on how I can solve this?

(running EE 2.5.5 and Structure 3.3.8)

Answer (score 0):

On mobile so I must be brief... Try this in your Channel Entries tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    ...other params...
    dynamic="no"
    entry_id="{structure:page:entry_id}"}
```

That way you force the entry id to get the right page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, this results in an even more unusual behaviour when the URL requested doesn't match a page... the channel entries tag now somehow finds a random page and serves that instead. (I'm guessing something in the Structure plugin is matching the URL incorrectly to a page ID)

Comment: Huh, I use structure a lot and hard forcing the structure page entry_id usually works perfectly.,. I notice you are a bit out of date on EE and Structure, perhaps it's a bug.

Comment: Perhaps... will be upgrading soon so will try again then and cycle back with further input.